# Capitalization of the model name (Mongoose)?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose-models

Why the name of the Model is Capitalized.
As in their documentation, they have capitalized it.

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', size: 'string' });
var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', schema);
```

Why is `Tank` capitalized here? Is there any specific reason?

Sorry if this is not a good question. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is merely a coding convention. The `Tank` model is being viewed as an instantiable class:

```
var small = new Tank({ size: 'small' });
```

According to [typical coding conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java), class names should be `UpperCamelCase` with the first letter capitalised, and instance variables should be in `lowerCamelCase` (as should methods).

Answer (score 1):

Reference [Mongoose Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#compiling)

> ```
> var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', size: 'string' });
> var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', schema);
> ```
>
> The first argument is the *singular* name of the collection your model
>   is for. ** Mongoose automatically looks for the plural, lowercased
>   version of your model name. ** Thus, for the example above, the model
>   Tank is for the **tanks** collection in the database.